# AWS Lambda Python aioboto3 exception AttributeError: 'ResourceCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'Table'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have done a project with AWS SAM CLI in Python and I'm trying to read DynamoDB items asynchronously from Lambda functions using `aioboto3` + `asyncio`.

My code seems fine but I am getting an exception every time I read or write to the dynamo database.

Handler code:

```
import os

import json
import asyncio
import datetime
import aioboto3


def get_hello(event, context):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(get_hello_async(event, context))


async def get_hello_async(event, context):
    name = event['queryStringParameters']['name']

    item = await get_item(name)

    if item['date']:
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item['date'] / 1000)
        message = 'Was greeted on {}'.format(date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S'))
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            'body': json.dumps(message)
        }


async def get_item(name):
    dynamodb = aioboto3.Session().resource('dynamodb')
    table = await dynamodb.Table(os.environ['TABLE_NAME'])
    record = await table.get_item(Key={'name': name})
    return record['Item'] if 'Item' in record else None
```

The exception I'm getting via AWS Cloudwatch:

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'ResourceCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'Table'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 11, in get_hello
    return loop.run_until_complete(get_hello_async(event, context))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 17, in get_hello_async
    item = await get_item(name)
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 34, in get_item
    table = await dynamodb.Table(os.environ['TABLE_NAME'])
```

It is as if the `aioboto3` library does not have the `Table` attribute when the DynamoDB resource is called, however the official `boto3` library does.

Answer (score -1):

`session.resource()` is also an async function. You need to `await` on it.

Comment: Could you give a little more feedback on why not using `await` leads to said error?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Error while getting an item in database: object ResourceCreatorContext can't be used in 'await' expression